# could not upload image in media library

Tags: images, uploads

I am trying upload an image in media library, on browsing the images its shows  that the image is uploading, but after that image could not be uploaded and it shows this  error--

> top-long-bg.jpg Missing a temporary folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open file `wp_config.php` and add code

```
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/temp/');
```

via ftp in the folder `/wp-content`, create a new catalog `/temp/`